# How do irepeat code if an error is met?

Tags: c++, loops, error-handling

i need to make a basic game of guessing and don't know how to loop the code so the user inputs his answer again when meeting an error. This is the whole code i have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>      //srand
#include <time.h>       // time
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

void error(std::string s)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(s);
}

int main()
{
    int characters ,length ,guess_number = 0,letter_number = 0, total_guess = 0 , err_count = 0;

    char letters,guess;
    std::vector <char> v;
    std::vector <char> answer;
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of different characters: ";
    std::cin >> characters;
    std::cout << "Enter the pattern length ";
    std::cin >> length;

    if(length > 26)
    {
        error("Length can't be over 26");
    }

    srand (time(NULL));

    for(int i =0; i < length ; i++)
    {
        letters = rand()% (26-(26-characters))+65;  //ascii code for Upper case letters. we discard the 26-characters to only generate random numbers up until how many characters.
        letter_number++;
        v.push_back(letters);                          //random letters
    }
    for(int i = 0;i <v.size(); i++)
        std::cout << v[i];

    try
    {
        while(guess_number != letter_number)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter your guess: ";
            while(std::cin >> guess)
            {
                answer.push_back(guess);                       //user guess
                if (std::cin.peek() == '\n')
                break;
            }
             total_guess ++;

            if(v.size() != answer.size())
            {   
                error("Answer too short");
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            {
                if(v[i] == answer[i])
                {
                    guess_number++;

                }
            }

            if(guess_number != letter_number)
            {
                std::cout << "you have guessed " << guess_number << " characters correctly." << std::endl;
                guess_number = 0;
                answer = {};
            }

            else if(guess_number == letter_number)
            {
                std::cout << "You have guessed " << guess_number << " characters correctly" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "You guesses the pattern in " << total_guess << " guesses";
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    catch(std::runtime_error& error)
    {
        std::cerr << "error: "<< error.what() << std::endl;

       return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically i don't know how to make the program to ask the user again if the user inputs a shorter answer than the random letters vector. After this part:

```
if(v.size() != answer.size())
   {   
       error("Answer too short");
   }
```

After i run it and input something shorte the program gives the error and ends instead of going again.

Comment: How about you just [*`continue`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) the loop?

Comment: Is it really an exception if the user enters too few characters? What I mean by that is, it's not really exceptional circumstance is it? How about you just maintain a flag that represents if their answer was too short. 

Then in your while loop check the flag (if the users answer is too short then just loop again, where you throw the error just set the flag to true, else set it to false).

Comment: Or like some programmer dude just said, use continue to skip back to the start of the loop again if the answer was too short.

Comment: What would be exceptional is like the keyboard unplugged mid stream (I don't even know if that's possible but it gives you an idea of what I mean by exceptional). Don't use exception when you could just use other construct like a bit.

Comment: yea i know it's a weird exception but my problem required me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because once the error is triggered you're catching the error (outside the `while` loop, essentially terminating it) and then even executing `return 1` (terminating the program). Also, since the error can stop the execution early, you should always clear the `answer` right after starting each step. So you should do three things:

1. Wrap the `try...catch` inside the `while`
2. Remove the `return 1` line from the catch, so the code continues executing
3. Move `answer = {};` to the top of the `try...catch`

It should look something like this:

```
while(guess_number != letter_number)
{
    try
    {
        answer = {};
        std::cout << "Enter your guess: ";
        while(std::cin >> guess)
        {
            answer.push_back(guess);                       //user guess
            if (std::cin.peek() == '\n')
            break;
        }
         total_guess ++;

        if(v.size() != answer.size())
        {   
            error("Answer too short");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            if(v[i] == answer[i])
            {
                guess_number++;

            }
        }

        if(guess_number != letter_number)
        {
            std::cout << "you have guessed " << guess_number << " characters correctly." << std::endl;
            guess_number = 0;
        }

        else if(guess_number == letter_number)
        {
            std::cout << "You have guessed " << guess_number << " characters correctly" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "You guesses the pattern in " << total_guess << " guesses";
            break;
        }

    }
    catch(std::runtime_error& error)
    {
        std::cerr << "error: "<< error.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here you go: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##pVbfb9owEH7PX3Fj2khEm1ZI46EBJCrtrdrbHqZtQsYxxGqwI9sJYxV/OzvbARICXaVagJK783e/vrOhRXG7onS//8gFzcuUwZhLbRQj62lwkmmT5nwRZ1Nw6@5OKyLShoHha3ZUox6soKGvGDVSnUGyP5QVZhoEleQpMKWkClH88IABcLECHQUvgcUzmZIbcCpVCgs9r62jJNgFARcG1oSL8LDBCmhGFKGGKQ03ORMrk8HNqmRaz0W5XjAFE7hHhUGLpgSMNCSfO0srgBsb2ZxKdGzfk8B5sOjgd2sPmzi5C9JnC2NrNIXqqoYIvWGqoUYvBsZj6H0VCIx5MyBr51kuIeXLJVOsldoD9JrbuYDptKF@HbogNnwBdXUuIHlNnTJfhrXlFIajyMl8ue3yDek9eQtKRN/AgoGs0Nlw1Is8@M5DOfpAaDsZfvv@9BRFtY8lYtjmcZjcJ/g7PgSHL4PBuc@6/tgWixdGnyAcjm7t91SCKBqMviSWk0RTzoFKZB@6ge9FgaFRotkBJ4YNwyprSlTqCtQCQmKAFPkWVkwwRQxzTuUaPHk0lAVYcuaQIVnXRGwbjYjPYq4ZNxgkR0UVF6XO5gtCn8M6oCiBq@vurnZf29bl9Ug0Z0SFdc0bwBD2Z/2L4seDuNEBJDt2oIo1/8sQ7NSBDqmqn/w3dtD3cJPxnIWtUfswaed93kijtsfnk9QuPyIYy8suaSkukXorSwXO8XEuDssH1eS2s4taRm3XJ/eNzvhdydWmlJrVIXSw@BKOAcQFY89hBJMJ9H@JftQxXuAR/NxOYdc2ap5TlkdB21d46Jstfp2GF5zljN@O93qYZ774RkrQmVTmMMWniFqvbeq46b1CnsvFtkEjkWxRfMD40q1Md59dTbp1qtGt3q5Trjfw9XoEbTIiDSEjFfNBsRR6VtxyYM2aNxSVSuHVkG9jZ@vwmEjzJHgtUX8fvZIXy/F0O09u8q7kfrwjuf/l1vXknejWdYXj64CaA@Bc1sa95G3TFHSpQYmhWdj9o/HZT0R05ZDycaOJi8OZ4gGEz@4x3mTE4Bxezn3XvBcVMyVmiE3d7ffDYBjMghl@HoN/) *Note: I altered your code to always "generate" AB as the pattern*